# Can it make sense to use LaTeX as common (canonical) data format?

Tags: formatting, data-structures

Some folk I know are looking for a common (canonical) format for sharing some structured data between different systems & databases. One sub-group, who publish this data in magazines using LaTeX suggest that LaTeX itself could be used as the common data format, even though most users aren't working with LaTeX

I have no a priori opinion on this idea, but it does seem as if people more commonly use JSON or YAML for common data formats. Also, the community we are talking about is very broad across many operating systems and technical backgrounds, and I am concerned that setting up LaTeX may be more complicated than other solutions.

Does anyone have any relevant experience of this, or any incisive arguments?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this is a bad idea, as there is no tooling to get structured data in, but especially out, of LaTeX, and there are no practical ways to check data integrity/constraints beyond "is this valid LaTeX". But maybe to clarify could you add an example of the type of data to your question, and maybe a proposed format in JSON and in LaTeX? That would make it easier to discuss advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks Marijn - I will try to provide an example, but it may me take a day or two.

Comment: I'd agree with Marijn that the answer is "no", for the reasons given --- except for when the data you're trying to share happens to describe the structure of a LaTeX document! Otherwise, stick with the established formats, including domain-specific formats that aren't equally well-suited for all structured data but happen to serve the needs of one particular niche particularly well. Oh, and also: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: I agree with the "no" fraction. If necessary, nearly every common data format will have an exporter to LaTeX (tables).